# Query to new table SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

the following query returns results successfully using the only two tables in by database. I'm having problems directing the results to create a new table.

```
    select Object.Xref, Object.area, Object.screen, Object.field, locator.data insert into Results from Object inner join locator on Object.area = locator.area and Object.screen = locator.screen and Object.field = locator.field
```

I get the following error:  "near "insert": syntax error:"

If I take the insert out. it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT` goes first. Try

```
INSERT INTO Results
SELECT o.Xref, o.area, o.screen, o.field, l.data 
  FROM Object o JOIN locator l 
   ON o.area = l.area 
  AND o.screen = l.screen 
  AND o.field = l.field
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/40a61/1)** demo